# Place google map on website

Tags: google-maps

I want to place google map on my website, how can I place google map on my website? can you give any already placed google map link and explain how can I add it on my website also!!!

Answer (score 1):

Search on Google Maps for the map you want to embed, then click the cog icon at the bottom right.

This will give you the options for "share or embed".

The "embed" option will give you the code for an iframe along the lines of this:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d18880.59998835847!2d-0.40254354999999997!3d53.734739000000005!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x4878955012bab063%3A0xb390bc68e9f8014!2sHU4!5e0!3m2!1sen!2suk!4v1405340572035" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
```

Just paste that into your code where you want it to appear.  You may wish to tweak the `width="600" height="450"` values so that it fits on the page.

If you are using a wysiwyg editor, you may need go into "html view" to paste this and also check that iframes are accepted (some editors strip them by default but you can usually turn this off).